# How can I get C# code to recognize a control from a xaml file in a .NET MAUI application?

Tags: c#, xaml, maui

I have a checkbox control in a MainPage.xaml file like this:

```
<CheckBox x:Name="chkViewAll" Color="Black"/>
```

and in my MainPage.xaml.cs file I have a method setup as

```
public static DataTable GetPasswrds()
```

Now the reason I have the method setup as static is because this will run when the program first starts up and it's located in the MainPage file. This way I don't have to declare an object first to use it which would cause an error anyway because of the file that it is in. My problem is, in this method, I need to get access to the IsChecked property of the checkbox I mentioned earlier. But because I've setup the method as static, it won't recognize it. But if I remove static, yes it will recognize it but when the program first runs, I will get a global error because I have to declare MainPage before I use this metod and that would be declaring it more than once.

So how can I get this static method in MainPage.xaml.cs to recognize that checkbox?

Or is there some kind of binding that can be done?

Comment: If the method is called when the program starts up, then it doesn't belong into the `MainPage` class. Use a service instead, which you can use in your App.xaml.cs as well as in your MainPage.xaml.cs.

Answer (score 0):

Use the `static` modifier to declare a static member, which belongs to the type itself rather than to a specific object.

A `static` function, unlike a regular (instance) function, is not associated with an instance of the class.

A `static` class is a class which can only contain `static` members, and therefore cannot be instantiated.

> How can I get C# code to recognize a control from a xaml file in a
> .NET MAUI application?

Based on your description, I don't think it's appropriate for you to use `static` here.

If you want to recognize a control from a xaml file, you can use the `x:Name` property directly(e.g. `chkViewAll.IsChecked`).

You can refer to the following code:

```
public partial class MainPage : ContentPage 
{

      public MainPage()
      {
            InitializeComponent();

          GetPasswrds();
    }

    public void GetPasswrds() {

        if (chkViewAll!=null)
        {
            if (chkViewAll.IsChecked)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The starus is checked");
            }
            else {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("The starus is not checked");

            }
        }
    }
}
```